# Page Titles on Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, status-completed

1. The login page doesn't have the "Stack Exchange Data Explorer" suffix.
2. The page titles in the Browse section don't change when you change the selected tab(featured, recent, favorite and popular)
3. Some of the pages have hyphens in the title and some don't:

   With: Users, My account, FAQ
   Without: About, Compose Query, Browse Queries

Comment: Thanks, Ill get this sorted tomorrow, lots of cleaning up to do now that my big refactor is done.